# Text By Line And Image Generator PHP Script

Tags: php, image

I wanna write a simple php script... I have text list and I have image list.

Images are okay and text list are okay...

But text by line and image by number (like that 1, 2 , 3) equal..... First text and first image....

I wanna write text on image. Refresh the page. And wadaa my text on image...

I wrote a script but not worked...

Here : https://www.sendspace.com/file/6f7as4

Please help me... Sorry my english... Thank you

Comment: You can include your code directly into your post. Please do this and show us what you have done so far

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code according to this

`$kaynak = "img/aa.jpg";$kaynak1=$kaynak.rand(1,5);$resim =imagecreatefromjpeg($kaynak);$çýk = "img/b.jpg";$beyaz = imagecolorallocate ($resim,255,255,255);$siyah = imagecolorallocate($resim,0,0,0);`